# symfony redirect to external url with headers

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have been trying to create a redirection to an external url but I need to set the authorization and a cookie in order to login in, I wrote something but I'm always stuck at the login screen:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($url, 302, array('Authorization' => 'Basic XXXXX'));
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie($cookie[0], $cookie[1]));

return $response
```